# PicklingError from Dask when calling Client.Submit

Tags: python, multiprocessing, dask

I have a backtesting engine which I have tried to parallelise using dask. I can treat each week of data independently, so I thought I could easily parallelise by firing off a worker that would create a complete instance of the backtest engine and run it on one week of data.

Here is the outline code I tried based on the [Dask Futures docs](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/futures.html).

```
from dask.distributed import Client
from backtest_engine import *

def run_backtest(start_date, end_date):
    engine = backtest_engine()
    engine.price_spread = 2
    engine.emulate_ticks = True
    engine.run_walk_forward(start_date, end_date, 'my_market', my_strategy_class)
    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = Client()
    a = client.submit(run_backtest, datetime(2017,9,3), datetime(2017,9,9))
    b = client.submit(run_backtest, datetime(2017,9,10), datetime(2017,9,17))
```

The code fails on the call to `client.submit()` with:

`_pickle.PicklingError: Could not pickle object as excessively deep recursion required.`

Is there something wrong with the code, or is my approach fundamentally flawed in some way, or are there restrictions in what calls I can make within a worker?

Ian

For background: `run_walk_forward()` loads an HD5 file into a Pandas dataframe, iterates over the dataframe to produce results, then writes the results to disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following MRocklin's advice above, I ran through my class element by element, and here are the issues that were causing the exception stated above.

**1. Class With Inner Functions**

Credit to Emlyn O'Regan for this [blogpost](http://medium.com/the-infinite-machine/python-function-serialisation-with-yccloudpickle-b2ff6b2ad5da) that made me realise that I had code which did the following and cannot be pickled:

```
class A:
   def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
   def do_something():
        # access self.parent

class B:
   def my_func():
      a = A(self)
      a.do_something()
```

Fixed by rewriting the code to pass the attributes as parameters to the appropriate method.

**2. Class Referenced Global Variables**

This was just hastily written code where I'd placed some constant variables (parameters set once at start up) outside of the class definition, then referenced from within a class that needed to be pickled.

Fixed by moving the variables into the class definition.

**3. Class Defined In Main Module**

I had inherited from a base class in the main module to create a new class with overridden behaviour. The new class lies in the **main** name space, so could not be pickled.

The solution was simply to move the definition of the inherited class into a separate file so it resided in a namespace other than **main**. i.e. instead of:

*my_script.py*

```
class A:
   # define stuff

if __name__ == "__main__":
   # do stuff which will instantiate A
```

create two files:

*class_a.py*

```
class A:
   #define stuff
```

*main.py*

```
   from class_a import A
   if __name__ == "__main__":
   # do stuff which at some point will instantiate A
```

Ian

Answer (score 4):

Dask uses cloudpickle for function serialization.  I recommend trying `cloudpickle.loads(cloudpickle.dumps(obj))` on your function and each of your arguments to `client.submit`.

For example it could be that some dependent of your function, like `backtest_engine`, relies on a lock or open file that is not easily serializable and sent between machines.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I had read in the docs  the suggestion to run a pickle.dump on the objects, but had hoped there was be a more obvious issue/solution to my problem that would allow me to avoid that work!